# Maximum of $2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+2x_3x_4$

Tags: linear-algebra

Calculate max of $$g(x)=2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+2x_3x_4$$ if $x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2=1$.

I do not know how to attack this problem, so a help on the way would be great.

Comment: have you tried lagrange multiplier

Comment: Since you have tagged it linear-algebra, perhaps you have learned about representing quadratic forms by symmetric matrices, then the maximum you seek is the maximum eigenvalue of said matrix.

Comment: I would **really** like to answer this question, but [a recent meta post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12991/why-do-you-answer-questions-on-math-stackechange) has finally helped me realize that there's just no real point in doing that. ;-)

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, it's in my linear algebra course. I do not, however, know how to solve it using linear algebra-tools.

Comment: Well, I told you what the linear algebra tools are: there is a standard way to represent a quadratic form by a symmetric matrix, and when that's done, you just have to look at the eigenvalues. Have a look at http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math133s213/notes/Quadratic%20forms2013.pdf

Answer (score 2):

The matrix $$A=\pmatrix{0&1&0&0\cr1&0&1&0\cr0&1&0&1\cr0&0&1&0\cr}$$ represents $g$, in the sense that if $x$ is the column vector $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$, then $g(x)=x^tAx$. The maximum value of $g(x)$ on $x$ of length 1 is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

This is explained at length at http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math133s213/notes/Quadratic%20forms2013.pdf

Comment: Thanks. I am now wondering about the fact stated on [page 2 in the pdf](http://rutherglen.science.mq.edu.au/math133s213/notes/Quadratic%20forms2013.pdf)

"Since A is symmetric, we can choose an orthogonal matrix $P$ such that $P^t AP = D $ is a diagonal matrix."

I googled *symmetric matrix eigenvalues* and got to [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition) the sentence "To see orthogonality..."

Comment: "To see orthogonality, 
suppose x and y are eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$. Then
$\lambda_1 \langle x,y \rangle = \langle Ax, y \rangle = \langle x, Ay \rangle = \lambda_2 \langle x, y \rangle$
so that if 
$
\langle x, y \rangle \neq 0$ then 
$\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, a contradiction; hence $\langle x, y \rangle = 0$."

Is that it?

Comment: There's a bit more to it than that. You have to notice that if $x_1,\dots,x_k$ are eigenvectors corresponding to the same eigenvalue, you can use Gram-Schmidt to replace them with orthogonal vectors. And you have to show that if $A$ is symmetric then it is diagonalizable, that is, there is a basis for ${\bf R}^n$ consisting of eigenvectors of $A$. That's somewhat harder, and I don't cover it in my notes. But for any particular symmetric matrix, such as the one in this problem, you don't need the theory; you can find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, and see the orthonormality.

Answer (score 1):

Establish the Lagrange multiplier $L$ that given by:
\begin{equation}
L=(2x_1x_2+2x_2x_3+2x_3x_4)+\lambda(x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2-1)
\end{equation}
For the sake of simplicity, variables of $L$ have been ignored. Calculate the extreme conditions:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_1}=2\lambda x_1+2x_2=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_2}=2\lambda x_2+2(x_1+x_3)=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_3}=2\lambda x_3+2(x_2+x_4)=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial x_4}=2\lambda x_4+2x_3=0\\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial \lambda}=x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2-1=0
\end{equation}
The solution is:
\begin{equation}
x_1=\pm\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{20}}\\
x_2=\pm\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{20}}\\
x_3=\mp\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{20}}\\
x_4=\mp\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\sqrt{\frac{5-\sqrt{5}}{20}}\\
\end{equation}
Note that there are four solutions but only these two are maximum.

Comment: Nice solution, but I cannot use it. The problem need to be done with toold from linear algebra.